# В чем разница функции и метода в Swift

Tags: swift

В методичке эти параграфы находятся в разных местах и вроде считаются не совсем одним и тем же, но я не понял в чем отличие функции от метода?

Comment: ну без гугла, предположу, что метод это фунуция в инстансе класса, имеющая доступ ко всему в scope класса, например к self

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да,  но ведь все func обьявляются внутри классов.  Или в свифт может быть такое что func обьявлена за пределами класса?  В андроиде допустим нужно обьявить класс и в класс обьявляются все его методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Функции** существуют вне класса и никакой с ним связи не имеют
- **Методы** - это функции, которые работают с переменными класса и являются его интерфейсом

Answer (score 1):

Напишу свое (может и ошибочное) мнение.

Метод - слово для функции в ООП.

По определениям что то, что то - именованный участок кода, в них можно передать данные (параметры) и получить данные которые возвращают.

При этом метод может оперировать данными внутри своего класса, т.е. их не нужно передавать как параметры и он привязан к объекту.

И да, в Swift Вы можете писать свои функции, как и переменные, вне класса и обращаться к ним из любого места своей программы.

Поэтому возможно будет правильно называть все что внутри класса методами, а вне - функциями. А может и не совсем.